# I need to convert that query in laravel Query

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `events` 
 WHERE (`customer_bookable` = 1 and template = 1 ) 
    OR (`customer_bookable` = 0 and template = 0 ) 
   and (`start_date_time` BETWEEN '2017-09-01 00:00:00' and '2017-09-21 00:00:00') 
   And (profile_id = 10) 
   and (event_live_status = 1) 
   and (class != 0) 
   and (privacy_status = 1)
```

Comment: Hi there! What have you tried yourself? We can help you with (adjusting) your code, but we don't write it for you.

Comment: Here is the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries on how to convert a SQL query into Laraval Query Builder code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need help with the 'or' part? You can use closures where you would use parenthesis in SQL:

```
...
->where( function ($query) {
   $query->where('customer_bookable',1)
         ->where('template',1);
 })->orWhere( function ($query) {
   $query->where('customer_bookable',0)
         ->where('template',0);
 })
 ...
```

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can see where it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your query may look like this,

```
$events = DB::('events')
    ->where( function ($query) {
         $query->where('customer_bookable',1)
               ->where('template',1)
               ->orWhere('customer_bookable',0)
               ->orWhere('template',0);
    })
    ->where( function ($query) {
          $query->whereBetween('start_date_time',['2017-09-01 00:00:00' and '2017-09-21 00:00:00'])
          ->where('profile_id',10)     
          ->where('event_live_status',1)
          ->where('class','!=',0)
          ->where('privacy_status',1);
     });
```